# square every element of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Given a measurable set $A$, if we square every element $B=\{a^2: a\in A\}$, is $B$ still measurable?
I have no idea about this question, can someone help me?

Comment: I think you want to specify A to be a lebesgue measurable subset of the real numbers

Comment: Yes, assume that A is lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Hmm, the collection of $A \subseteq [0, \infty)$ such that $f(A)$ is Borel (where $f(x) = x^2$) is a $\sigma$-algebra and it contains all the open intervals, so the collection contains all Borel subsets of $[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_+=\bigl\{a^2\,|\,a\in A\cap[0,+\infty)\bigr\}$ and let $B_-=\bigl\{a^2\,|\,a\in A\cap(-\infty,0]\bigr\}$. Since $B=B_+\cup B_-$, if you prove that $B_+$ and $B_-$ are both measurable, then $B$ is measurable.

Now, note that if $s(x)=\sqrt x$, then $B_+=s^{-1}\bigl(A\cap[0,+\infty)\bigr)$. Since $s$ is continuous and $A\cap[0,+\infty)$ is measurable, $B_+$ is measurable. A similar argument shows that $B_-$ is measurable.

Comment: I think this works if "measurable" means "Borel measurable", but not "Lebesgue measurable". There are continuous functions such that the inverse image of a Lebesgue measurable set is not Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @Alex Zorn: and that is your new lemma ;).